# Consent screen for Google doesn't fit within iPad popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm using GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch to display the login screen for Google Drive in a popover. I get past the sign-in -- everything is fine there -- and the web view shows the consent screen. But the size of the consent screen data is more than twice the size of the popover (320 x ~460), requiring the user to scroll to see the Accept button. There's a lot of white space on all sides of the content, but even without that it I don't think it would all fit.

Here's how it looks on a Retina display iPad 2 running iOS 7 (life size):

[image]

[image]

I tried changing the web view in the XIB to "scales page to fit" but it had no effect. I haven't made any other changes to the XIB; both the container view and the web view are "scale to fill". Auto-layout is off for the file.

Here's how I invoke the login view controller. I'm given the controller for the popover which is currently on-sceen. That controller is a few layers down in the navigation stack.

```
- (void) attemptLogin: (UIViewController *) controller
    {
        GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *newController = nil;

        if (![self isUserLoggedIn])
            {
            newController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:kGTLAuthScopeDrive
                clientID:_googleAppKey clientSecret:_googleAppSecret keychainItemName:_googleKeychainKey
                delegate:self
                finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuthorizer:error:)];
            [[controller navigationController] pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
            [newController release];
            }
    }
```

This isn't a disaster on the order of a dinosaur-killer asteroid, but it sure is annoying. Am I doing something wrong or is this loosy-goosy display the way it's "supposed" to work?

Comment: Out of interest have you found a way to remove the arrow buttons?

Comment: I haven't tried, but it would be easy to delete the buttons from the XIB. (Assuming you're compiling the code into your app,  not into a library.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code on the viewDidLoad method of the ViewController:

```
[self.myWebView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,
                               self.view.frame.origin.y,
                               self.view.frame.size.width,
                               self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

This will force the content to be displayed within the frame size.

Comment: This doesn't work. The authorization view (supplied by Google) uses a single UIWebView for both stages of the login process. The frame of the web view is correct. I had to use KVO to watch for the webView being loaded, but then -- and always after -- the frame is correct. I checked the scalesPageToFit property, and it's YES. I tried forcing the web view's scrollView content size, and that did nothing. The HTML that's being loaded is apparently just scaled for a large popover, and I can't force it to fit into my small one.

Comment: Also, by the way, this is intensely inefficient code, both for the reader and compiler. A better way is [newController.webView setFrame:self.view.frame]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to fix this is to change the size of the popover when I create the authorization view controller:

```
[newController setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(768, 620)];
```

Kind of dopey, but it solves the problem.